# Index into dataframe by column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to access certain entries based on particular column values.  For example...the data frame has four columns 'A, B, C, D'

I want to grab a particular entry where 'A=1' and another where 'B=42'.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called boolean indexing, where you slice the dataframe based on a condition:

```
df[df['A']==1]
```

or if both have to be true:

```
df[(df['A']==1) & (df['B']==42)]
```

But I recommend that you go thorugh the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html, and specifically on boolean indexing: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing